# Using a loop to figure out the number of tries left

Tags: java, loops

I have this celebrity guessing game where the user has to guess a celebrity’s name, given only a portion of the letters in the name. 
I give the player the “clue” (e.g.rge oney) and read in their guess. The program should have a loop that allows them to keep guessing. If they guess incorrectly 3 times, give them a hint If they guess incorrectly a fourth time (after the hint), they lose the game (and you should tell them who the celebrity was).

I'm having trouble with the loop. this is what I have so far.

```
 System.out.println("Celebrity Guessing Game"); 
 String celeb = "John Lennon";

 System.out.print("Choose your difficulty (easy/medium/hard): ");
 String difficulty = input.nextLine();
 int maxtry = 3;
 if (difficulty.equals("easy"))
 {
     System.out.println("Here is your clue: " + celeb.substring(1, 4) + " " + celeb.substring(5,10));
    }
 else if (difficulty.equals("medium"))
 {
     System.out.println(("Here is your clue: " + celeb.substring(0, 3) + " " + celeb.substring(4,9)));
    }
 else if (difficulty.equals("hard"))
 {
     System.out.println(("Here is your clue: " + celeb.substring(2, 4) + " " + celeb.substring(5,7)));
    }


 System.out.print("What is your guess? ");
 String guess1 = input.nextLine();
 System.out.println("guess1 = " + guess1 + "   celeb = " + celeb );

 while (!guess1.equals(celeb) && maxtry == 3  ) {

    if (!guess1.equals(celeb) && maxtry == 3) {

    maxtry--; 
    System.out.println("Try Again." + " Number of guesses left : " + maxtry);
}     

   if   (guess1.equals(celeb) || guess1.equals("john lennon")) {
            System.out.println("Good Guess, you are correct!");
 }
```

This is my output:

Celebrity Guessing Game

Choose your difficulty (easy/medium/hard): easy

Here is your clue: ohn Lenno

What is your guess? john lennon

guess1 = john lennon   celeb = John Lennon

Try Again. Number of guesses left : 2

Good Guess, you are correct!

^ Why is it going through both if statements??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in checking condition. It have following problems:

- It should be `maxtry > 0` instead of `maxtry == 3`
- Instead of `equals()` use `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Following is corrected code snippet:

```
while (!guess1.equalsIgnoreCase(celeb) && maxtry > 0  ) {

    if (!guess1.equalsIgnoreCase(celeb) && maxtry > 0) {

        maxtry--; 
        System.out.println("Try Again." + " Number of guesses left : " + maxtry);
}
```

**Note:** You are not reading input from user for other tries.